# How to override an expression bodied member in a scan screen using ScanExtension?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to write a customization for the Scan Move screen and I need to override the boolean CanOverrideQty which determines if the Set Qty button is enabled. Here is my code:

```
public class ScanMoveExt : ScanMove.ScanExtension
{
    protected override bool CanOverrideQty => (!Base1.DocumentLoaded || Base1.NotReleasedAndHasLines) &&
        (Base1.SelectedLotSerialClass?.LotSerTrack != INLotSerTrack.SerialNumbered || Base1.SelectedLotSerialClass?.LotSerAssign == INLotSerAssign.WhenUsed);
}
```

This doesn't work because it says there is no suitable method to override. I also tried [PXOverride] but I don't believe that works on expression bodied members. It didn't give me an error but it also didn't execute my code. I could probably decorate the scan command and set the enabled on SetQtyCommand to achieve the same result but for my own information I'm curious how to override these expression bodied members in a ScanExtension. I couldn't find any examples of this in the documentation about customizing WMS screens after 2021R1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortuantly I do not believe you are going to be able to do this.

[When overriding a protected member within Acumatica](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/accessing-or-overriding-protected-methods-in-graph-extensions-using-pxprotectedaccess/)
the entry in your graph extension must be decorated with the `abstract` keyword. Given how the logic is written to change the value that is returned by `CanOverrideQty` you would need to have an expression body which unfortuantly is not allowed with the `abstract` keyword.

```
[PXProtectedAccess(typeof(ScanMove.Host))]
public abstract class ScanMoveExtension_ProtAccess : PXGraphExtension<ScanMove.Host>
{
    [PXProtectedAccess]
    protected abstract bool CanOverrideQty => true;
    //cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're a bit confused on what exactly expression bodied members are.

Expression bodied members are actually just syntactic sugar provided by Microsoft that allow us to not have to use brackets for things that can be done in a single "line"/expression.

What you're looking at is specifically a readonly expression bodied property.

You can tell the difference between expression bodied methods and expression bodied properties by the lack/existence of parenthesis.

Expression bodied property :

```cs
public bool IsDirty => true;
```

Compiles to :

```cs
public bool IsDirty
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Expression bodied method :

```cs
public bool IsActive() => true;
```

Compiles to :

```cs
public bool IsActive()
{
    return true;
}
```

With that out of the way, I do not believe you can override PXGraph properties within PXGraphExtensions, although an Acumatica employee may correct me if I am wrong. I am not personally familiar with the part of Acumatica that ScanExtension is from, however I did test this myself and could not override the property, so it looks like you will have to override base Acumatica functionality another way.

Comment: I thought that you could override properties in a PXGraphExtension and that the problem I was having was specific to ScanExtension, but now I see that you can't do this in PXGraphExtension either. So I will go with my alternate method for the customization.